# jQuery Boilerplate passing element as option

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, plugins

I'm using the jQuery boilerplate as plugin pattern
more info about jQuery boilerplate can be found here : https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/boilerplate/

Im want to pass an element as default option, but i can't access it
here is the (simplified) code :

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

    /*creating the default settings*/
    var pluginName = 'pluginName',
        defaults = {
            nextElem:$('#right') 
        };
    console.log(defaults.nextElem); // return : Object[] , not cool

    /*merging default and options, then calling init*/
    function Plugin( element, options ) {
        this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options);
        this.init();
    }
    Plugin.prototype = {
        init: function() {
            /*trying to access the default nextElem */
            console.log(this.options.nextElem); // return : Object[] , not cool
            console.log(this._defaults.nextElem); // return : Object[] , not cool
            this.options.nextElem = $('#right');
            console.log(this.options.nextElem);// return : Object[div#right] , cool
        }
    };

    $.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
        return this.each(function () {
            if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
                $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ));
            }
        });
    }
})( jQuery, window, document );
```

and the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery1.8.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pluginName.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $('#img').PluginName();
    });
    </script>
    <div id="img"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why did the two 3 `console.log(this.options.nextElem)` don't return my jQuery object ?

Comment: BTW, why do you keep your `script` tag within the `body` element? Either move it into the `head`, or [move it to the bottom of the `body` tag (together with all other scripts)](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're running your plugin's code before `document.ready`.

Even though you're only *calling* your plugin function after the document is ready, your plugin function itself *does* run before that; the initial call to `$('#right')` is done before `document.ready`.

---

A different approach would be to pass a string instead of an actual object:

```
var pluginName = 'pluginName',
    defaults = {
        nextElem: '#right'
    };

function Plugin( element, options ) {
    this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options);
    this.options.nextElem = $(this.options.nextElem);
    this.init();
}
```

Comment: @nicolast - Like I said, you're *calling* the plugin on `document.ready`, but any code inside your main closure (outside of your class) runs immediately.

Comment: @nicolast - Nope. That just creates a closure for your local variables, but it runs immediately.